# How do I remove duplicate results by looking for max date?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, max

I know I have duplicate results from this query because the tables ReleaseHistory and IterationHistory have multiple records per ReleaseID and IterationID. I would like to only select the records with max date from dbo.ReleaseHistory and dbo.IterationHistory. How would I do that in this query? SQL SERVER 2008

```
SELECT     dbo.Assignable.AssignableID AS ID,
           dbo.EntityType.Abbreviation AS Entity, 
           dbo.General.Name, dbo.Assignable.Effort, 
           dbo.Assignable.EffortCompleted, 
           dbo.Assignable.EffortToDo, 
           dbo.EntityState.Name AS State, 
           dbo.ReleaseHistory.Name AS Release,   
           dbo.IterationHistory.Name AS Iteration, 
           dbo.General.CustomField3 AS [Scrum Team]
FROM       dbo.Assignable INNER JOIN
           dbo.General ON dbo.Assignable.AssignableID = 
             dbo.General.GeneralID INNER JOIN
           dbo.EntityType ON dbo.General.EntityTypeID = 
             dbo.EntityType.EntityTypeID INNER JOIN
           dbo.EntityState ON dbo.Assignable.EntityStateID = 
             dbo.EntityState.EntityStateID AND 
           dbo.EntityType.EntityTypeID = 
             dbo.EntityState.EntityTypeID INNER JOIN
           dbo.ReleaseHistory ON dbo.Assignable.ReleaseID = 
             dbo.ReleaseHistory.ReleaseID INNER JOIN
           dbo.IterationHistory ON 
             dbo.Assignable.IterationID = 
             dbo.IterationHistory.IterationID LEFT OUTER JOIN
           dbo.CustomField ON dbo.General.CustomField3 = 
             dbo.CustomField.CustomFieldID
WHERE     (dbo.Assignable.ProjectID = 4054)
GROUP BY dbo.Assignable.AssignableID, 
           dbo.EntityType.Abbreviation, 
           dbo.General.Name, 
           dbo.Assignable.Effort, 
           dbo.Assignable.EffortCompleted, 
           dbo.Assignable.EffortToDo, 
           dbo.EntityState.Name, 
           dbo.ReleaseHistory.Name, 
           dbo.IterationHistory.Name, 
           dbo.General.CustomField3
```

Comment: What database platform and version are you on (MySQL, SQL Server, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brian,

I am amusing you are doing this in MS SQL and there will always be at least one record in  ReleaseHistory and IterationHistory tables. If assumptions are correct then you can simply use CROSS APPLY to get top 1 record from both tables.

```
SELECT
    dbo.Assignable.AssignableID AS ID ,
    dbo.EntityType.Abbreviation AS Entity ,
    dbo.General.Name ,
    dbo.Assignable.Effort ,
    dbo.Assignable.EffortCompleted ,
    dbo.Assignable.EffortToDo ,
    dbo.EntityState.Name AS State ,
    Release ,
    Iteration ,
    dbo.General.CustomField3 AS [Scrum Team]
FROM
    dbo.Assignable 

    INNER JOIN dbo.General ON  dbo.Assignable.AssignableID = dbo.General.GeneralID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.EntityType ON  dbo.General.EntityTypeID = dbo.EntityType.EntityTypeID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.EntityState ON  dbo.Assignable.EntityStateID = dbo.EntityState.EntityStateID 
        AND dbo.EntityType.EntityTypeID = dbo.EntityState.EntityTypeID 
    CROSS APPLY( SELECT TOP 1 name Release FROM ReleaseHistory WHERE ReleaseID = Assignable.ReleaseID ORDER BY MaxDateColumn) a
    CROSS APPLY( SELECT TOP 1 name Iteration FROM IterationHistory WHERE IterationID = Assignable.IterationID ORDER BY MaxDateColumn) b
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CustomField ON  dbo.General.CustomField3 = dbo.CustomField.CustomFieldID
WHERE
    ( dbo.Assignable.ProjectID = 4054 )
GROUP BY
    dbo.Assignable.AssignableID ,
    dbo.EntityType.Abbreviation ,
    dbo.General.Name ,
    dbo.Assignable.Effort ,
    dbo.Assignable.EffortCompleted ,
    dbo.Assignable.EffortToDo ,
    dbo.EntityState.Name ,
    dbo.ReleaseHistory.Name ,
    dbo.IterationHistory.Name ,
    dbo.General.CustomField3
```

Comment: Using your query I got Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CROSS'.

Comment: Cross apply require a alias. since I can't execute that in my environment only thing I can say "BAD CODING/TESTING SHRINI!!!!"

Comment: Which parts of this do I need to replace?  CROSS APPLY( SELECT TOP 1 name Release FROM ReleaseHistory WHERE ReleaseID = Assignable.ReleaseID ORDER BY MaxDateColumn) a

Comment: Rather than ReleaseHistory join, you place the cross apply which will return only one row. You can add appropriate list of columns you want from that row. Just add the necessary alias to the columns. Same goes for the IterationHistory. Just remember, the TOP 1 is required. Without that it will be a crash (nested query returning multiple results).

Comment: Brian, keep in mind the way you used the "CROSS APPLY" was similar to a "INNER JOIN". If you ever need to join in a similar way where the result may or may not contain data, you will have to use "OUTER APPLY". Any ways, you are welcome. I myself learning and discovering new things in SQL every day.